# JavaScript RegExp to match all subpaths from location

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following

```js
const location = '/level_1/level_2/level_3/';
```

I would like to find a `RegExp` to pass to

```js
location.match(regexp);
```

so that I can get all subpaths within the full path

```js
"/level_1/"

"/level_1/level_2/"

"/level_1/level_2/level_3/"
```

Ideally, the `RegExp` would work no matter the number of levels.

I have already tried

```js
location.match(/^\/.*?\//);
```

but it only returns the first occurence

```js
"/level_1/"
```

Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: You have to use the `g` flag to return multiple matches. But it won't return overlapping matches, so you can't do what you want with a single regexp.

Comment: Why don't you just use `location.split('/')` and then make all the concatenations you want?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, of course some JavaScript would work to achieve that, but I wanted to let the power of RegExp do the job ! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop that tries finding matches of every length until it fails.

```js
const loc = '/level_1/level_2/level_3/';
const result = [];
for (let i = 1; ; i++) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`^(?:/.*?){${i}}/`);
  const match = loc.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    result.push(match[0]);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit different than the request, as I'm not sure about arbitrary matching groups in regexp. But the String.prototype.split takes a regexp or a string to split on. So could you do something like:

```
const loc = "/level_1/level_2/level_3/"
const strippedString = loc.match(/^\/(.+)\/$/)
let result = []
if (strippedString.length === 2) {
  strippedString[1].split("/").forEach(path => {
    result.push(`/${path}/`)
  })
}
```